# Trying to make RegEx for 4 simple conditions

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to make a regular expression for 4 simple conditions :

1. AdobeSoftware should be "Adobe" and "Software" --> Get 2 strings "Adobe" and "Software"
2. adobeSoftware should be "adobe" and "Software" --> Get 2 strings "adobe" and "Software"
3. ADobeSoftware should be "ADobe" and "Software" --> Get 2 strings "ADobe" and "Software"
4. adobe1Software should be "adobe" and "1" and "Software" --> Get 3 strings "adobe" and "1" and "Software"

I am not able to achieve last one. What I have done :

```
("
 + "?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|("
 + "?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|("
 + "?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|("
 + "?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<!(^|[A-Z]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])"))
```

How can I achieve the above via regular expression?

Comment: Are you asking, for example, how the string, `"I use adobe1Software  every day"` can be changed to `"I use adobe 1 Software  every day"`? What about `"adobecatSoftware"`, `"adobe 1 Software"`, `"adobeSofwares"`? Please edit to explain in words what you are trying to do. Questions expressed in terms of examples only are rarely unambiguous. You need a precise statement of the question with examples used for illustration only.

Comment: What's the result for "adobe12software"?

Comment: Are you planning to get capture groups or something? In that case: `([aA][dD]obe)(1)?(Software)` could be what you are after. However, you might want to clarify

Comment: I have updated the question you can have a look on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could get those matches using capturing groups instead of using lookarounds and make the group for the digits optional:

```
\b([A-Z]*[a-z]+)(\d+)?([A-Z][a-z]+)\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary to prevent the word being part of larger word
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]*[a-z]+` Match 0+ chars A-Z to match `A` or `AD`,  and 1+ chars a-z to match `obe`, `dobe` or `adobe`
- `)` Close group
- `(\d+)?` Optional capture **group 2** to match `1`
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match a char A-Z and 1+ chars a-z to match `Software`
- `)` Close group
- `\b` `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vjoCdu/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/4ITqCc)

Or match 0+ digits in the second group `(\d*)`

You can then either check if there is a group 2 present, or in the latter case check for the value of group 2.

Example code

```
String regex = "\\b([A-Z]*[a-z]+)(\\d+)?([A-Z][a-z]+)\\b";
String string = "AdobeSoftware\n"
     + "adobeSoftware\n"
     + "ADobeSoftware\n"
     + "adobe1Software";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Output

```
Adobe
Software

adobe
Software

ADobe
Software

adobe
1
Software
```

Comment: when adding this regex with or (|) I am getting [adobe, 1Software] but it should be [adobe,1,Software]

Comment: @ShanuGarg Why do you want to add `|`? See this demo https://ideone.com/4ITqCc

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `([aA][dD][oO][bB][eE])([0-9]?)([a-zA-Z]+)` meets all 4 of the conditions you have described.

`([aA][dD][oO][bB][eE])` will match the word "Adobe" with any combination of upper and lower case letters. `([0-9]?)` will match an option digit in between the two words. `([a-zA-Z]+)` will match any sequence of letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression:

```
([A-Z]*[a-z]+)(\d+)?([A-Z]*[a-z]+)*
```

In general, the expressions will try to find 3 groups:
1) A string that starts with a lower case, 1 or more uppercase
2) Optional a number of any size
3) One or more strings that start with a lower case, 1 or more uppercase